# How do I make a JButton hit the enter key when pressed?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, enter

So in my code, I have 2 `JTextField` inputs that need input for the rest of the program to work. Both of them contain variables that cannot be left empty for the rest of the program to work. The problem is that whenever you enter something into the text field, you have to press enter in the end and that process is not that straightforward in the program as you are not able to see whether or not you have already pressed enter without looking into the console.

```
ActionListener buttonlistener2 = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        frame2.setTitle("Multiplayer");
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        JLabel labelM = new JLabel("Geben sie eine Höhstzahl ein:");
        JTextField hZahl = new JTextField();
        JLabel labelN= new JLabel("Mit wie vielen Rateversuchen wollen sie spielen?");
        JTextField rVers = new JTextField();
        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
```

Now I want the `JButton` `b` to press enter for both text field `hZahl` and `rVers` when pushed. How do I achieve that?

This is what button `b`does so far:

```
ActionListener buttonlistener3 = new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) { 
                        if((arr[0] > 0) && (arr[1] > 0)){
                            frame3.setTitle("1 Player Game");
                            frame3.setVisible(true);
                            JLabel labelB = new JLabel("Erraten sie die Zahl:");
                            JTextField rVers1 = new JTextField();
                            labelB.setBounds(50, 105, 400, 70);
                            rVers1.setBounds(45, 150, 100, 30);
                            frame3.add(labelB);
                            frame3.add(rVers1);
                            rVers1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                                        System.out.println("Rateversuch: " + rVers1.getText());
                                        int r = Integer.parseInt(rVers1.getText());
                                        arr[2] = r;
                                        System.out.println("werte " + arr[1] +" " + arr[3] +" " + r);
                                        
                                     
                                        if(arr[1] == 1){
                                           JLabel lv = new JLabel("Letzer Versuch!");
                                           lv.setBounds(50, 50, 400, 70);
                                           lv.setForeground(Color.red);
                                           frame4.add(lv);
                                        }
                                        
                                        tru = arr[3] == arr[2];
                                            if(r < arr[3]){
                                            labelB.setText("Die Gesuchte Zahl ist größer.");
                                            rVers1.setText("");
                                            arr[1] = arr[1] -1;
                                            
                                        }
                                        if(r > arr[3]){
                                            labelB.setText("Die Gesuchte Zahl ist kleiner.");
                                            rVers1.setText("");
                                            arr[1] = arr[1] -1;
    
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                        
                                       
                                    
                                    if(tru){
                                            frame4.setVisible(true);
                                            JLabel cor = new JLabel("Richtig!");
                                            JLabel win = new JLabel("Sie haben Gewonnen");
                                            
                                            
                                            cor.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 100);
                                            win.setBounds(50, 150, 300, 70);
                                            Font labelFont = cor.getFont();
                                            String labelText = cor.getText();
                                            cor.setForeground(Color.red);
                                            win.setForeground(Color.green);
                                            frame4.add(cor);
                                            frame4.add(win);
                                        }
                                        
                                    if(arr[1] == 0){
                                            
                                            frame4.setVisible(true);
                                            JLabel cor = new JLabel("Falsch!");
                                            JLabel win = new JLabel("Die Zahl war: " + arr[3]);
                                            
                                            
                                            cor.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 100);
                                            win.setBounds(50, 150, 300, 70);
                                            Font labelFont = cor.getFont();
                                            String labelText = cor.getText();
                                            cor.setForeground(Color.red);
                                             win.setForeground(Color.green);
                                            frame4.add(cor);
                                            frame4.add(win);
                                        }
                                        
                                    if(arr[1] == 0){
                                            
                                            frame4.setVisible(true);
                                            JLabel cor = new JLabel("Falsch!");
                                            JLabel win = new JLabel("Die Zahl war: " + arr[3]);
                                            
                                            
                                            cor.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 100);
                                            win.setBounds(50, 150, 300, 70);
                                            Font labelFont = cor.getFont();
                                            String labelText = cor.getText();
                                            cor.setForeground(Color.red);
                                            win.setForeground(Color.red);
                                            frame4.add(cor);
                                            frame4.add(win);
                                        
                                        }
                                    System.out.println("werte neu " + arr[1] +" " + arr[3] +" " + r);
                                }
                                });
                        }

                
                    }
                };
                
            b.addActionListener(buttonlistener3);
        }

    };
```

Comment: You can have the system simulate a button push, but I think you're WAY over-complicating things.  Extract your actions and then put them into an ActionMap.  Then when you want trigger the code attached to a button, you just look it up in the ActionMap and use it.

Comment: What is an action map? How do I use that? Sorry I basically just started doing anything with java so i am not that familiar with the terminology!

Comment: When writing code for buttons and such you should be utilizing the Action interface, usually by creating a class that extends AbstractAction.  This way if you want to tie that action to a button, popupmenu, or menu bar, it's all the same code.  You can put that Action into an ActionMap keyed however you like.

Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: *Now I want the jbutton b to press enter for both JTextField hZahl and rVers when pushed* - that is not how this problem should be solved. The logic in the ActionListener for the button should simply validate that data has been entered into each text field. If not, you display a JOptionPane with the warning message. If data is contained in each then you validate it is the proper format. If both are valid then you do your processing.

Comment: Judging by `frame3`, `setBounds`, inconsistent code indentation and seemingly random amounts of blank lines in the code, this code seems a mess. Given your lack of experience, I suggest you put aside GUIs for a while and work on the basics. If you wish to slog on, [edit] to add a [mre].